# Fragment Backstacking correctly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having some troubles implementing proper backstacking into my application. I thought I knew what I was doing but it turns out it worked only because of a fluke, and I'd rather fix it to be the correct way to do things.

This is using the template provided by Google in Android Studio mind you.

First, my setup look like this; my `content_main.xml` set up like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
....>
<FrameLayout
    ....
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my main activity, i have a function which switches fragments by taking in an id like this:

(I know ill probably get some slack from using android.app.Fragment rather than the support library, I'm willing to switch if it will help my cause, but then I run into different problems, more on that if the answer turns out to be "switch to support library")

```
private void drawFragmentFromId(int id)
{
    android.app.Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mainFrame);
    if (id == R.id.nav_overview)
    {
        //fm is a global fragment manager, is that bad practice?
        if(currentFragment.getTag() == "F_SETTINGS")
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(currentFragment.getId(), oFrag, "F_OVERVIEW").commit();
        else
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(currentFragment.getId(), oFrag, "F_OVERVIEW").addToBackStack(currentFragment.getTag()).commit();
    }
....
}
```

I have the `if(currentFragment.getTag() == "F_SETTINGS")` clause in there because ideally, I'd like to NOT add the settings fragment to the backstack. That is to say, if the user goes to the overview fragment, then the settings fragment, then the fragment 'foo', and then hits the back button, ideally, I wouldnt want the application to go back to the settings fragment, but skip it entirely. Let me know if I'm doing something wrong here or if there's a good practice way of doing it.

And in my `onBackPressed` I let `super.onBackPressed()` handle the drawing of past fragments.

For some reason this makes the app crash sometimes, telling me that I'm trying to draw a fragment that has already been drawn. To be exact:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: OverviewFragment{7ee61cf #0 id=0x7f0d0072 F_OVERVIEW}`

The app seems to crash if i try to, for example, go to the overview fragment, then settings, then overview again, and then hit the back button. however, if I add the settings fragment to the backstack, this process seems to work perfectly fine.

If i go to the overview fragment, then the settings then another fragment, call it 'foo', then the app does something really weird, it skips the settings fragment, as desired, but then it doesn't replace the foo fragment with the overview fragment, it just places the overview fragment on top.

I'm guessing the problem lies with the app's default `onBackPressed()`. It probably doesn't know what fragment to replace with the new one, but quite honestly, I have no clue how to rectify this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And thank you for reading through this.

**EDIT**:
Entire logcat stacktrace:

```
11-16 15:22:26.948 24151-24151/com.projects.mocks.mocks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.projects.mocks.mocks, PID: 24151
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: OverviewFragment{134836e #0 id=0x7f0d0072 F_OVERVIEW}
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1219)
                                                                          at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:1630)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1587)
                                                                          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:578)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2503)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:180)
                                                                          at com.projects.mocks.mocks.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:143)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2477)
                                                                          at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2664)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2730)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:543)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:315)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3981)
                                                                          at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2253)
                                                                          at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1874)
                                                                          at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1865)
                                                                          at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2230)
                                                                          at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
                                                                          at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: please post a complete stack trace from logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look's like I've figured out my desired effect. And I'm going to post this as an answer for anyone else that might be faced with the same problem as I was.

It seems that my code was right, I was just missing one tiny piece of code that makes the entire thing work as expected.

The problem with my above code is that I'm trying to achieve this effect:
user clicks [A], then clicks [C] then any other fragment, call it, [B].
I'm not adding [C] to the backstack, so you would think that `onBackPressed()` would just skip [C] when doing the reversal, but the way that the backstack works is it takes a sort of a 'state snapshot' and will reload that exact state. Since I'm not adding [C] to the backstack, all it knows to do, from my understanding, is to re-add [A], but [B] never gets removed.

the solution was to do the following:

```
private void drawFragmentFromId(int id)
{
    android.app.Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mainFrame);
    if (id == R.id.nav_overview)
    {
        //fm is a global fragment manager, is that bad practice?
        if(currentFragment.getTag() == "F_SETTINGS"){
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            fm.popBackStack(); //it was this guy here. that's all I was missing.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(currentFragment.getId(), oFrag, "F_OVERVIEW").commit();
        }
        else
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(currentFragment.getId(), oFrag, "F_OVERVIEW").addToBackStack(currentFragment.getTag()).commit();
    }
....
}
```

[It was this answer that pointed me in the right direction.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28985763/3192656) (a little further down, it's a verbose answer)